# Can't find a language(-interpreter) that supports running a fixed amount of steps and then pauses

Tags: java, runtime, virtual-machine, metaprogramming, julia

### Problem:

I'm looking for a programming language and runtime whose execution can be "timed" in steps of code.
To be more concrete I need a language runtime/interpreter that can execute like 100 steps(not lines). After the execution the called method (of the runtime) returns while keeping its state. Later you can tell the runtime to continue execution for another 100 steps and so on.
It's somewhat like a VM only for execution of a single program.

---

### Question:

Are there any runtimes for given languages that fullfill those criteria?

Preferred languages are Julia(julialang.org) and Java but I'm looking forward to all tips you can have for me. (keywords for search, problems in realisation, partial solutions, other languages that support it etc)

---

### What i need it for:

I'd like to create a mod for minecraft that has codeable blocks but in order to prevent the whole minecraft world to be stuck due to players mistake and to be able to save the game/state at any time i need to be able to execute code of these codeable blocks in a fixed amount of time and save the current state of that codeable block's runtime after any of these runs.

Aaron aka rapus95

Comment: Almost all debuggers do "1" step ("singlestep") and then display the result.

Comment: are the debuggers that you're refering to also capable of saving their state? (even over the lifetime of the process -> saving to file etc)

Comment: There is "stepping" under the assumption that the "whole memory state" is implicitly preserved, which is where most debuggers operate.   You seem to want, on top of that, something that can extract the full interpreter/execution state ("save the game state") from the memory image and save/restore it to a file.  That's a lot harder; you either have to know how to discover all that state, or the interpreter has to be designed to make it accessible for  you.   Not having any facts, I'd bet Minecraft is not specificaly designed to offer you either of these.

Comment: I assume you misunderstood my use case, I need the runtime of that interpreter/debugger to be savable not minecraft itself. Because if the debugger is, then I can pause and store the current state of the debugger and tell minecraft to save the state of that codable block within its world

Comment: I'm assuming that Minecraft has its own interpreter; surely you dont intend to find/build another? Does it provide the single-step capability? Minecraft will save its own state for you?  Surprising, but OK.   Why does the debugger really need to save its own state?  Most debuggers can be started up with the application in whatever state it is in, let you inspect the state and step from there.  A debugger *may* have modes; then there might be something to save.

Comment: The debugger needs to be capable of saving the state of execution (current memory used by the debugged program and current program pointer) not its own state. 
Minecraft doesn't save the state of its own execution but the state of the world (from a different view you may even consider minecraft as a debugger for the world mechanics, means simulating reality step by step while being able to store the current reality after every cycle of simulation)

Answer (score 2):

A practical solution might be to use Java threads and have a timer thread interrupt the work thread when its time limit is reached. However, there is an interesting abstraction known as "engines" that can be implemented using call/cc in Scheme: http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/examples.html#g208 This lets you pair a piece of work to do (represented as a 0-argument procedure) with an amount of "fuel" that it's allowed to consume. The "thread" stops when it runs out of fuel.